# Angular App (PWA) runs in ng serve but not with http-server

Tags: angular, typescript, service, progressive-web-apps, worker

I'm building a PWA with Angular.  Everything was working great until suddenly, I keep getting 404 Error every time I navigate to a new component, while serving in dist/project with http-server.  I haven't changed any code since deploying to git

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio, Restarting my Computer, Updating my Service Worker in the Ctrl+Shift+i menu, Resetting in git.  No avail.

Here's my angular routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes=[
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'whoconebioassayphase1', component: WhoConeBioassayPhase1Component},
  {path: 'editwhoconebioassayphase1', component: Editwhoconebioassayphase1Component},
  {path: 'exphutintro', component: ExpHutIntroComponent},
  {path: 'exphut', component: ExpHutComponent},
  {path: 'editexphutintro', component: EditexphutintroComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WhoConeBioassayPhase1Component,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    Editwhoconebioassayphase1Component,
    ExpHutIntroComponent,
    ExpHutComponent,
    EditexphutintroComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule

  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FbIhi</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monteserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "fb-ihi",
  "short_name": "fb-ihi",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

and ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls":[
          "htts://fonts.googleapis.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }],
    "dataGroups": [
      {
        "name":"jokes-api",
        "urls": ["https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"],
        "cacheConfig":{
          "strategy": "freshness",
          "maxSize": 20,
          "maxAge": "90d",
          "timeout":"5s"

        }
      }

    ]
}
```

I expect to be able to click on a button in my app and be routed to the next component.  However, instead I'm getting a not found error.

Comment: The Angular Docs section on deployment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment may be helpful

Comment: What is the exact not found error in the console?

Comment: "Uncaught (in Promise) DOMException... ngsw-worker.js:1

Comment: That looks like a possible video error (google search) - do you have something in your app that plays video?

Comment: No, but I did notice that the service worker works fine on other computers and on my friend's google chrome Android app, but not on the laptop that I'm developing on... Does that sound familiar at all?

Comment: try go to developer options (F12) then Application, choose ClearStorage and press the Clear site data. don't forget refresh the page

Comment: Type this into the chrome  address bar (chrome://apps/) and if you see your app icon, right-click to remove/uninstall

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  I didn't have enough space on my computer.  Deleted a bunch of videos off my hard drive and fixed it immediately.